# Attach a csv file to work object

Tags: pega

I have a XML file which I have to convert in CSV file and then attach in Work-Object?

I already tried by writing an activity and use pxConvertResultsToCSV activity and then try to attach file using Link Object method but by this all the result would come in a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few steps to be followed...

1) Parse the XML using activity method `Apply-Parse-XML`. 
   You will get the XML data in a `PageList`.

2) Now create on `Rule-Obj-Html` rule. In the code part create on table

```
<table border="1">    
<pega:forEach name="YourPageListPage.PageList"> // --> the pagelist in which got the info from xml.

<tr>    
   <TD>
     <pega:reference name="$THIS.COLUMN1"/> // --> property name
  </TD>
  <TD>
     <pega:reference name="$THIS.COLUMN2"/> // --> property name 2
  </TD>
      </tr>
    </pega:forEach>
</table>
```

3) Now using `Property-Set-HTML` get the stream of your html rule in some param variable(for example **param.pyFileData**)
Also create one local variable as **strFileData**.

Decode the stream Using `Java` step. And use this code.

```
 String atr = (String)tools.getParameterPage().getParameterValue("pyFileData");

byte[] byteArray=(byte[])atr.getBytes();

//encode the byte array into Base64.
 strFileData = Base64Util.encodeToString(byteArray); // strFileData is local variable mentioned in activity.
```

4) Now create a page of class `Data-WorkAttach-File` and set following properties on that page.

```
.pxRefObjectKey --> pzinskey of work object
.pxAttachKey    --> any key, maybe current date time
.pyAttachStream --> your stream which you got from 3rd step (local.strFileData )
.pyNote         --> any note
.pxAttachName   --> "filename.csv"
```

Rest I guess already know..
 Save this page using `Obj-Save`

5) Use `Link-Objects` to attach your attachment page to work object.

Thats it.